Derived tensor by perfect complex preserves exact triangle in singularity category?
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $\operatorname{D}_{sg}(R)$ be the singularity category of $R$, i.e., the Verdier localization of $D_b(\text{mod } R)$ by the thick subcategory of perfect complexes. We recall that  objects of $\operatorname{D}_{sg}(R)$ are precisely the objects of $D_b(\text{mod } R)$, however, morphisms are very different. In particular, If $X,Y,Z \in D_b(\text{mod } R)$ are such that $X\cong Y$ in $\text{D}_{sg}(R)$, then it need not hold that $X \otimes^{\mathbf L}_R Z\cong Y \otimes^{\mathbf L}_R Z$ is $\text{D}_{sg}(R)$, however, it is true if $Z$ is a perfect complex.
My question is: If $X\to Y\to Z\leadsto$ is an exact triangle in   $\operatorname{D}_{sg}(R)$ and $G$ is a perfect complex, then do we have an induced exact triangle $X\otimes^{\mathbf L}_R G\to Y\otimes^{\mathbf L}_R G \to Z\otimes^{\mathbf L}_R G \leadsto $ ?

@LeoAlonso: hmm, I am confused now ... how do you explain the non-triviality of things like Remark 2.3 or equation (2.9.1) of https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~takahashi/dsdec6.pdf  then?

@LeoAlonso: your comment would also imply that the subcategory in Lemma 2.4(1) of https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~takahashi/dsdec6.pdf is the $0$ subcategory (because the Koszul complex $K(x)$ is perfect complex), no?

@LeoAlonso: actually, although $G$ is perfect, $X \otimes^{\mathbf L}_R G$ need not be perfect at all, so I am not sure how you concluded the triangle to be $0$ ....

@LeoAlonso $- \otimes R$ in complexes (which is same as derived tensor product, by k-flatness of perfect complex R) induces the identity functor on either derived or singularity category.

To the OP: you have luckily noticed that you're confused, because as written, this question makes very little sense. There are three possible ways to fix it. First is to try to interpret it literally (that you start with a triangle in $D_{sg}$): but $G$ is literally zero object in singularity category. Another way (which is probably closer to what you had on mind) is that you start with a diagram in either chain complexes, homotopy category of chain complexes, or derived category, which becomes a triangle after localising down to singularity category. Then you tensor it with a perfect, and...
